# Program that arranges four 4-bit binary numbers

Tags: c

I have tried reading this assignment multiple times. I couldn't interpret what objectives we have to accomplish.

**Write a program in C that arranges four 4-bit binary numbers as follows**:

```
1001
1010
1000
1001
1111
```

**For each display the following pattern**

```
0110    0**0
1001    *00*
1110    ***0
1001    *00*
1110    ***0
```

The pattern in the example above represents the letter ‘B’

**Questions:**

1. Draw the same pattern with 5-bit binary number.
2. Make changes in the program such that it prints A-Z.

Comment: The purpose is to be able to print the pixels which would be on to represent a character. Start with B and then do it for all the other letters.

Comment: Does this pattern look like a B?

Comment: It does given the limit number of pixels. If you use 5-bit you can do something a little closer to a B.  I would have made the first number 1110....

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @user3528438 - That's exactly the question

Comment: `arranges four 4-bit binary numbers ` Hmm - I count **five** 4-bit binary numbers

Comment: I guess it should be `1 -> '*'` and `0 -> ' '` (0 -> space). Also the first line should be 1110

Comment: well, a `B` in ascii is: hex 42 which is 0100 0010 in binary.  but maybe you meant a binary `B` which would be hex 0b which is 1011 in binary.    Please clarify (ask your instructor/TA for clarification)

Answer (score 0):

once you have a clear definition of the problem (always the hardest part when programming) then just loop through the bits,

printing a `*` when the bit is a 1

printing a  (space) when the bit is a 0.

How to loop through the bits (4 bits)

```
#define MAX_BITS (4)

for( size_t i=MAX_BITS; i > 0; i-- )
{
    if( bits & 1<i )
        printf( "*" );
    else
        printf( " " );
}
```

You could define the `bits` in an array then have an outer loop that steps through the array.  Then you could process several different bit strings in the same code execution

Changing to look at 5 bits would be just changing `MAX_BITS` to 5